# Span overlap issue

Tags: html, css

Hi all I am having some issues with getting my spans to work like I want. I have an alert and a search input box in a table header and I want the search box to float right and the alert to fill the rest of the space to the left of the search box. In the attached plunker I have gotten to to work by setting the width of the search box and then placing a matching right margin on the alert but this seems like a really dirty way to do it.

```
<span style="float:right;"><input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width:200px;" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></span>
<span class="alert alert-success" style="display:block;margin-right:210px;" role="alert">I don't want this to overlap the search</span>
```

Does anyone know of a nicer way to accomplish this? Here is a link to my [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QlYGXo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like margin, you can calc the width instead:

```
<th colspan="6">
  <span style="float:right;"><input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width:200px;" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></span>
  <span class="alert alert-success" style="display:block;width:calc(100% - 210px);" role="alert">I don't want this to overlap the search</span>
</th>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Aq45ZTXzR6i1vDEWEhSj?p=preview

In my opinion the cleanest option would be flex-box layout though, as this is really what it is for.

```
<th colspan="6">
  <div style="display:flex;align-items: stretch;justify-content: space-between;">
    <span class="alert alert-success" style="display:block;flex:1;margin-right:10px;" role="alert">I don't want this to overlap the search</span>
    <input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width:200px" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" />
  </div>
</th>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Aq45ZTXzR6i1vDEWEhSj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks this does what I want.

Comment: Would be interested to hear a reason for down votes. Happy to improve the answer if it is incorrect or missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`inline-block` instead of `block` which allows you to remove all the margins and stuff

Also, use `div` not `span` - `div` is a block level element

```
<div style="float:right;"><input class="form-control" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 0px;" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></div>

<div class="alert alert-success" style="display:inline-block;" role="alert">I don't want this to overlap the search</div>
```

[Here's updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yyDRUeJbW1oJQxYa5QZD?p=preview)

[Another updated plnkr splitting table](https://plnkr.co/edit/LJCOIS9sJtyVI27PGFmI?p=preview)

Comment: That sort of works but I want the green alert to fill the entire width to the left of the search bar. Div is not supported in a table header so I have to use spans.

Comment: Then I would split your table and set it to `width: 100%;` - otherwise you have to set widths - widths are bad if the site is going to be seen on many devices - % is good!

Comment: Added another plnkr @NathanKamenar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way, use `calc()` to come up with the width.

See updated plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2KIdmCBjpe3expY5c4LD?p=preview

```
<span class="alert alert-success" style="display:block;width: calc(100% - 210px)" role="alert">I don't want this to overlap the search</span>
```